# Eclipse plug-in project export

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have an eclipse plugin project with me. I have imported the project using eclipse committers edition. It had few missing JARs. I have added them too. Now its error free.

I want to export the plugin project as a plugin, so that can be installed in other eclipses.

I can export the project as an 'Eclipse Application'. It works fine. But I want it to be portable as plugin.

Comment: http://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/guide/tools/export_wizards/export_plugins.htm?cp=4_3_9_3_0

Comment: I exported it using the link above. But how do I install the plug-in in other eclipses in other machines? It gave me a JAR file when I exported it.